# WebAPI Help Pages: disable for Production release

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-helppages

I have developed a number of internal REST interfaces using the older WCF framework in VS 2010. The ability for it to generate help pages was handy for DEV and QA platforms, but for a production release it was easy to disable the generation of these help pages in the **web.config** file:

```
<standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="false" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"/>
```

I am now moving on to use the WebAPI framework instead (currently version 1 on VS 2012), but it doesn't appear to be as trivial to turn this feature off (i.e. I can't find any information on how to do this in a web.config file).

Certainly I can go ahead and do this by hand within the code itself, but surely there's an easier way; something akin to how WCF did it as described above. I'd like to use the web.config file approach since I already have the web.release.config transform files in place for other settings.

Any thoughts on best practices on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Web API doesn't have an out of box support with respect to web.config based enabling or disabling of helppage.

Some options you can consider:

- Since HelpPage is installed as an MVC area, when deploying to
  production you could just exclude this `HelpPage` folder.
- Create an action filter which returns 404 as suggested here: [Conditionally disable ASP.NET MVC Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11604773/conditionally-disable-asp-net-mvc-controller)

NOTE: for the above cases, if you are using the default Web API template, then yeah you would need additional step of display/not display the `Help` link from the navigation bar.

Comment: Yes, that's what it seems to be. In this case I am using the default template, but I don't think it'll be much work to get around this. I can certainly put an indicator in the web.config file for my own use within the code, or perhaps adding a RELEASE preprocessor directive and use good ol' #if #endif to block code out...

Comment: I just deleted the areas folder. Swagger API is much nicer than the default one anyway.

Answer (score 9):

Open the Global.asax.cs,modify your code like the following snippet code:

```
#if DEBUG
   AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
#endif
```

Because the help page is in the Area named 'HelpPage',so we can ignore it by the above code in the release or production environment.

Comment: This in itself is not a secure solution.If you enter the url in the browser you get an unhandled exception complete with stack trace and version information for both the .NET Framework and ASP.NET

Comment: @Chris That's only true if you are hitting the web API site from the server itself.  If you hit it remotely it just says "An error occurred while processing your request"

Answer (score 4):

You can use directive #if DEBUG to hide your code in realase

Comment: DEBUG flag is no use in most cases, because staging and\or test environment run without DEBUG.

Answer (score 2):

My solution for disabling `ApiController` controller:

- Uses WebConfig AppSettings config flag instead of (`#if DEBUG`)
- Before method is invoked `ExecuteAsync` intercepts the invocation and checks feature toggle (feature flag);
- if feature is disabled, returns `HTTP 410 GONE`
- If it's common for many controllers, move the code to controller's base class

The code:

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    public override Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var featureFlag = Convert.ToBoolean(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EnableTest"]);

        if (featureFlag == false)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Gone));
        }

        return base.ExecuteAsync(controllerContext, cancellationToken);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Combining Farb's and Soeholm's answers you get the Help page won't display AND it throws a 404 instead of a 500.

In Global.asax.cs

```
#if DEBUG // Make help page unavailable on release builds
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas(); 
#endif
```

and then in WebApiConfig.Register

```
#if !DEBUG 
    config.Routes.IgnoreRoute("help", "help"); // Make help page, which is now unavailable on release builds, throw a 404 instead of a 500.
#endif
```

Only I didn't use DEBUG, I made it a setting and change it with an xml transform  depending on where it's deployed.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone stumbles upon this question, here's how I managed to do it.

I added the following app setting to the base Web.config file:

```
<add key="ExcludeHelpPage" value="false" />
```

I then transformed this value in my LIVE or RELEASE config file, like this:

```
<add key="ExcludeHelpPage" value="true" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)"  />
```

Then I added the following code to the end of my WebApiConfig.Register method:

```
if (Convert.ToBoolean(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExcludeHelpPage"]))
{
    config.Routes.IgnoreRoute("help", "help");
}
```

This will make the help page unavailable for configs with ExcludeHelpPage set to true.

Comment: Your idea seems really great but it's not working for me. On my Register I have this `config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );`and I add your code after. But on the "HelpPageAreaRegistration.cs" I have `new { controller = "Help", action = "Index", apiId = UrlParameter.Optional });`  Any idea why the help is not being ignored?

Comment: This didn't work for me unless I combined it with Farb's answer (comment out RegisterAllAreas).