# Exclude HelpPage from WebAPI C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-helppages

i need to exclude my api help page during release mode 
i tried to add `ApiExplorerSettingsAttribute().IgnoreApi = true` in webapi config file but it's of no use
how can we achieve it?

Comment: What do you mean by 'exclude'?

Comment: I dont want to expose my api documentation in release mode,but in debug mode i need to show it

Answer (score 1):

If your help pages are in a separate folder then exclude that from source control and then create a branch from there. From that branch you can release/deploy your API. You should pull all your  API documentation in separate Wiki page if possible.

You should find this existing post really helpful [WebAPI Help Pages: disable for Production release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24168398/webapi-help-pages-disable-for-production-release)